# How can I interpret the following matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrices, vectors, estimation, parameter-estimation

The following lines are from a slide of Econometrics lesson. (The
topic is The Ordinary Least Squares Estimation)

"...By solving for $\widehat{\beta}$, we obtain the Ordinary Least
Squares (OLS) estimator: $\widehat{\beta}=(X'X)^{-1}X'Y=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}X_{i}')^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}Y_{i}$

Exercise: Verify that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}X_{i}'=X'X.$You may assume
$k=3$ for simplicity..."

I understand the way how we get $\widehat{\beta}$, but I don't get
what does $X_{i}$ stand for? As I know $X$ is a matrix, but in the
previous case: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}X_{i}'$ definitely looks like
the dot product of two vectors, which can't be, because the dot product of
two vectors is a scalar, and not a $A=X'X$ matrix. What
is $X_{i}$? The $i$th row(/column) of the matrix $X$? If it is indeed, I
still don't understand the exercise. Someone could solve me? Thank
you in advance.

Comment: If they don't specify the $X_i$, this is a badly written exercise. Maybe they mean that you have to find vectors $X_i$ such that $XX' = \sum X_iX_I'$ (which is possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the singular value decomposition of $X\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$, i.e., $X = U\Sigma V^T$ with $U\in\mathbb R^{m\times m}$ unitary, $V\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ unitary and $\Sigma\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ diagonal. Then
$$
X^TX = (U\Sigma V^T)^TU\Sigma V^T = V\Sigma^TU^TU\Sigma V^T = V\Sigma^T\Sigma V^T.
$$
Let the diagonal entries of $\Sigma$ be given by $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_k$ (where $k=\min\{m,n\}$). Then $\Sigma^T\Sigma = \text{diag}(\sigma_1^2,\ldots,\sigma_k^2)$ if $m\ge n$ or $\Sigma^T\Sigma = \text{diag}(\sigma_1^2,\ldots,\sigma_k^2,0,\ldots,0)$ if $n>m$. In the latter case, we set $\sigma_{m+1}=\ldots=\sigma_n = 0$. Then
\begin{align}
X^TX
&= \big[v_1|\ldots|v_n\big]\begin{bmatrix}\sigma_1^2&&0\\&\ddots &\\0&&\sigma_n^2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_1^T\\\vdots\\v_n^T\end{bmatrix} = \big[v_1|\ldots|v_n\big]\begin{bmatrix}\sigma_1^2v_1^T\\\vdots\\\sigma_n^2v_n^T\end{bmatrix} = \sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i^2v_iv_i^T.
\end{align}
If we now set $X_i := \sigma_iv_i$, then $X^TX = \sum_{i=1}^nX_iX_i^T$. Now, let $\Sigma_0 = \text{diag}(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_k)$. If we set $Z = U^TY$ (padded with zeros in the case $n>m$), then either ($m\ge n$)
$$
X^TY = V\Sigma^TZ = \big[v_1|\ldots|v_n\big]\big[\Sigma_0\,|\,0\big]\begin{bmatrix}z_1\\\vdots\\z_m\end{bmatrix} = \big[v_1|\ldots|v_n\big]\begin{bmatrix}\sigma_1z_1\\\vdots\\\sigma_nz_n\end{bmatrix} = \sum_{i=1}^nz_i\sigma_iv_i
$$
or ($n>m$)
$$
X^TY = V\Sigma^TZ = \big[v_1|\ldots|v_n\big]\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_0\\0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}z_1\\\vdots\\z_m\end{bmatrix} = \big[v_1|\ldots|v_n\big]
\begin{bmatrix}\sigma_1z_1\\\vdots\\\sigma_nz_n\end{bmatrix} = \sum_{i=1}^nz_i\sigma_iv_i,
$$
where we used the above convention $\sigma_{m+1}=\ldots=\sigma_n = 0$. So, if we put $Y_i = z_i$, then $X^TY = \sum_{i=1}^nX_iY_i$. Hence, finally,
$$
(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY = \left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_iX_i^T\right)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nX_iY_i,
$$
where $X_i = \sigma_iv_i$ and $Y_i = (U^TY)_i$.